# Different Releases in the same Jira Kanban board?

Tags: kanban, jira, kanban-board

We are a development team and we use a Kanban board (Jira) with different swimlines.

We have some tasks who are code related and other task who are not code related like investigations, query, improvements.

The different tasks go in different status (Done or Completed).

What we are looking for is to be able to release the two different swimlines in different times. Or maybe we are just not doing a correct use of our Kanban board.

Any suggestions is more than appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “release a swim lane”? Kanban systems usually track items of customer value with tasks as “column headings” by the way. Otherwise it’s just a task board.

Answer (score 1):

It's not something I have tried, but you may be able to do the following:

- Create two new Kanban boards and point them at the same project as you are currently using
- Add a filter to one new board so that only code related tasks are shown
- Add a filter to the other new board so that only not code related tasks
- Use your current board for day-to-day activities, but do releases from the new boards

This takes advantage of the fact you can have many Kanban boards all pointing at the same project in JIRA.

You would need some way of differentiating between code related and not code related tasks though (possible a custom field or label).